# 3-sphere universe

Tags: universe

I have just read on this site that there is a Newtonian solution to Einstein's field equation but that it is spherically symmetrical and therefore not isotropic (having a centre for example) and so considered not allowed. But if the universe is a 3-sphere it could be both spherically symmetric and isotropic. Would the Newtonian solution then be a possibility?

Comment: Could you add a link to the page where you read about the "Newtonian solution"? You can [edit] your post and add the URL  (Don't worry if you can't work out how to format it right, someone will be able to fix that for you.)